# Tor Browser Bundle v4 will not launch - possible Trusteer Rapport Interference

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, windows

For the last three days I have been trying to get the Tor Browser Bundle v4 to work on Windows 8.1. I have installed and removed the program and reinstalled probably ten times. I have downloaded the package from the Tor Project website at least six times. When I try and launch the bundle, I get the spinning circle for several seconds and then it disappears. Under Task Manager I see no processes marked as either Tor or Firefox.

I have found that the Tor Bundle will run on the Windows 8.1 machine, if it is booted into safe mode with network support.

I have found that the Tor Bundle will run on the Windows 8.1 machine, booted normally,  if a program called Trusteer End Point Protection (Rapport) is disabled.

Trusteer (Rapport) is required for my on-line banking, etc. I don't know which port Trusteer uses. I suspect a port conflict but have not been able to verify that.

Any suggestions appreciated

Comment: I have the exact same problem and also use trusteer for banking security.

Comment: anything in your windows event logs, especially under the application logs?

Comment: yes! Edited above

Comment: and I have now found that disabling TR and Tor works.

Comment: I am having the same problem with v6.01 It seems odd that I've never had an issue before now. I'm able to run v5.04 just fine. It's only after I upgrade to 6.01 that it won't run. For now I'm using 5.0.4 again. I will try updating to 6.01 and disabling Rapport to see if that changes anything, but I find it odd that it's only impacting the new version and not the older ones.

Comment: woah there, do *not* use 5.0.4. https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/security/known-vulnerabilities/firefox-esr/#firefoxesr38.4 stop, look at all those red marks above 38.4. those are all vulnerabilities that 5.0.4 is subject to. https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/11730/tor-wont-start-in-windows-8-1-used-to it's probably Rapport also this isn't an answer or a question, it would be better placed as a comment...

Comment: @PeterSmith I had to log in to conduct some business.  And nothing else works... I tried disabling rapport and it didn't solve the problem.  I've posted a question to get help. But until someone can get me another working version of Tor Browser - I am stuck using Tor 5.0.4. 

Is there some what to access previous versions of Tor like 6.0 - which worked fine for me?

Comment: Also - how do I change this to a comment, rather than an answer?

Comment: I have had the same problem (Tor browser not starting) on both Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 laptops. In both cases deactivating Trusteer End Point Protection (Rapport) solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a workaround other than to temporarily disable the Rapport software.
This problem is being tracked by Tor engineers here:

https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/13547

Also see this older, similar issue:

https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/8337

Please contact Trustee to encourage them to fix this issue.

Comment: I contacted Trusteer straight away when I found it was Trusteer at fault They have kept me updated and they are working on a fix right now Check for program updates regularly Paul

Comment: Yes and thank for this report you because I have exctly the same problem with Tor 6.0

Answer (score 1):

I have had this same issue before. Disable or uninstall IBM Security Trusteer Rapport ( Trusteer endpoint protection) and Tor browser should start working again.