# tor wont start in windows 8.1 - used to

Tags: windows

My TOR was working fine for some months. Just recently it wont open. I am on win8.1 - the little circle goes round for a bit and nothing happens.

SO I deleted the folder with TOR in, downloaded it again and reinstalled. Same thing. TOR wopnt start.

I have turned off my firewall and virus scanner. Still no joy.

I have also tried using the cmd prompt `c:\...\Tor Browser\Start Tor Browser` but no joy either.

Edit:
lots of errors in the log - here's one.

```
firefox.exe 
   45.2.0.0 
   00000000 
   MSVCR120.dll 
   12.0.21005.1 
   524f7ce6 
   c0000005 
   00013b0b 
   15c4 
   01d1c1979f303958 
   C:\Users\Edward\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\firefox.exe 
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Trusteer\Rapport\bin\MSVCR120.dll 
   dda818ab-2d8a-11e6-82d5-f01faf5d87dc
```

Does that help?

Comment: also I found that Truster Rapport was stopping tor on this thread - but in 2014 http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/4411/tor-browser-bundle-v4-will-not-launch-possible-trusteer-rapport-interference wonder if its a similar issue?